# Maximum file size that ODI can process

Tags: oracle11g

I have to transfer file data into a table. I am wondering if I can use ODI 11g (Oracle Data Integrator) for this. The followings are the specifications of the file:

1. It has around 200 million records.
2. Each record has 30 columns.

I wish somebody could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ETL tool that has a file size limit would be a pretty poor ETL tool.  I'm sure ODI (or any other marginally reasonable ETL tool on the market) can handle a file of that size.

The important question is whether it can load it quickly enough to meet your SLA.  That, in turn, will depend heavily on things like what you are doing with the file, what sort of hardware you have, and how you code the ETL process.  You haven't given us anything that we can use to even speculate on these questions.

Comment: Actually I am also not sure as of now regarding other specifications. But your answer as such has made complete sense to me. Thankyou very much.